# Аккордион. Второй клик

Tags: jquery, html

Простите мою ьупость. Но не могу сделать чтобы при нажатии на один элемент другие сворачивались. Не пойму куда писать и как писать это событие.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.content dd').hide();
    $('.content  dt').click(function(){
    $(this).next().toggle(100);
    return false;
    });
    $('content dd').next().hide();
    });

                </script>

<div class="content">
            <dl> Аккордион
            <dt>Новость первая</dt>
            <dd>Текст первой новости</dd>
            <dt>Новость вторая</dt>
            <dd>Текст второй новости</dd>
            <dt>Новость третья</dt>
            <dd>Текст третьей новости</dd>
            </dl>
            </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Есть готовое решение jquery.

```
<div id="accordion">

  <h3><a href="#">Section 1</a></h3>

  <div>Section 1 content</div>

  <h3><a href="#">Section 2</a></h3>

  <div>Section 2 content</div>

  <h3><a href="#">Section 3</a></h3>

  <div>Section 3 content</div>

</div>
<script>
  $("#accordion").accordion();
</script>
```

А по твоему примеру.

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 
$('.content dd').hide();
    $('.content  dt').click(function(){
        $('.content  dt').each(function(){
             $(this).next().hide();
        });
    $(this).next().toggle(100);
    return false;
    });
    $('content dd').next().hide();
});
```

Comment: Я сам хочу сделать не сильно прибегая к готовым решениям

Comment: Дописал как =)